# Google map is showing white screen in iOS when run second time?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, google-maps

I am displaying the google map using Google Maps SDK for iOS. When I start the view controller first time it shows the map fine. But when I goto the view controller second time it does not display the google map. It shows the blank screen. Actually I am passing the address in the google geo coding api from there I am getting the `lang & lat` then I am displaying the google map.

**Code for displaying google map**

```
//
//  GmapViewController.m
//  MyDex
//  Created by Admin on 8/18/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 com.vastedge. All rights reserved.
#import "GmapViewController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"
#import "UIKit+AFNetworking.h"
@import GoogleMaps;
@interface GmapViewController ()

@end

@implementation GmapViewController
{
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
    NSString *lat;
    NSString *lng;
    CLLocationDegrees latitude;
    CLLocationDegrees longitude;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView;
}

-(void)geoCodeAddress
{
    NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":/,."];
    self.address = [[self.address componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
    NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%@",self.address];

    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                 NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [manager GET:urlString parameters:nil
                                             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
                        {
                          NSArray * results = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
                          NSDictionary *records=[results objectAtIndex:0];
                          NSDictionary *geometry=[records objectForKey:@"geometry"];
                          NSLog(@"geomatry is %@",geometry);
                          NSDictionary *latLong=[geometry objectForKey:@"location"];
                          lat=[latLong objectForKey:@"lat"];
                          lng=[latLong objectForKey:@"lng"];
                          latitude=[lat floatValue];
                          longitude=[lng floatValue];
                           NSLog(@"main lat is %f",latitude);
                           NSLog(@"main lng is %f",longitude);
                          [self activityIndicator:@"hide"];
                          [self Loadgmap];
                        }
            failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
                {
                    NSLog(@"failure string is");
                     [self activityIndicator:@"hide"];
                    UIAlertView *alert =[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Unable to display map" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert show];
                }];
    [operation start];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self activityIndicator:@"show"];
    [self geoCodeAddress];
}
-(void)Loadgmap
{
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                            longitude:151.2086
                                                                 zoom:6];
    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = camera.target;
    marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker.map = mapView;

    self.view = mapView;
}

-(void)activityIndicator:(NSString *)show
{
        if([show isEqual:@"show"])
        {
            NSLog(@"loading shown");

            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
            activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
            activityView.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0f alpha:0.5f] CGColor];
            activityView.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
            activityView.frame = self.view.bounds;
            [self.view addSubview:activityView];
            [activityView startAnimating];
        }
        else
        {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
            [activityView stopAnimating];
            [activityView removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: I think you have to load map in main queue

Comment: How to do that? and what's the problem ?@chiragshah

Comment: I think you update your UI in other thread instead of the main thread

Comment: you can do this with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});

Comment: How does this thing works? Updating in main thread or in other thread?@chiragshah

Comment: you can do this with dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});

Comment: I have the same problem. Setting view in the main thread and setting it once. But still getting a gray map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{})` is a better practice, but the main problem of your `white screen` issue is the `view` in your `ViewController` get assigned to new value twice.

When the `[self Loadgmap]` is called in you `viewDidLoad()`, the `self.view = mapView;` is called. When your networking required is done, your `[self Loadgmap]` is called again, and the `self.view = mapView;` is called again, which make your view become a white screen.

You should only assign value to your `view` in the `viewDidLoad()` method, not later in other method calls.

To fix your problem, you can make a new method call `-(void)updateMap()`:

```
-(void)updateMap {
    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[lat floatValue]
                                                            longitude:[lng floatValue]
                                                                 zoom:6];

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = camera.target;
    marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker.map = (GMSMapView*)self.view;

    [((GMSMapView*)self.view) animateToCameraPosition:camera];
}
```

You should call it inside your network request success block:

```
 NSArray * results = [responseObject objectForKey:@"results"];
 NSDictionary *records=[results objectAtIndex:0];
 NSDictionary *geometry=[records objectForKey:@"geometry"];
 NSLog(@"geomatry is %@",geometry);
 NSDictionary *latLong=[geometry objectForKey:@"location"];
 lat=[latLong objectForKey:@"lat"];
 lng=[latLong objectForKey:@"lng"];
 latitude=[lat floatValue];
 longitude=[lng floatValue];
 NSLog(@"main lat is %f",latitude);
 NSLog(@"main lng is %f",longitude);
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [self activityIndicator:@"hide"];
     [self updateMap];
 });
```

Your `viewDidLoad()` should call `[self Loadgmap]` first to initialize a Google Map to your `view`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self activityIndicator:@"show"];
    [self Loadgmap];
    [self geoCodeAddress];
}
```

Full code snippet: https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/f66dd536382b1b16597d

[image]

Comment: Please check my updated question.Actually first i am calling the geoCodeAddress to get long,lat from address by making a network call ten i am passing the long,lat into the map.

Comment: That is the problem, you should not assign a value to your `view` after `viewDidLoad()`, when the network request is done, the `viewDidLoad()` already pass. Have you tried my code yet?  https://gist.github.com/ziyang0621/f66dd536382b1b16597d

Comment: Yeah your code just works fine.But what was the problem ?

Comment: How can i show the zoom button here.Like + and -.To zoom in and zoom out

Comment: The problem is your `[self geoCodeAddress];` is an asynchronous call, when the network request is done, the success block already outside of the `viewDidLoad()` scope, if you try to assign a value to your `view` by doing `self.view = mapView;`  it wont work. Also there is not default zoom button for Google Maps iOS SDK, it only has zoom gesture, if you want to add a + and - buttons, you have to make your own UIButton, and add to your map view.